# Eclipse birt prints another character instead of superscript three

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, birt

I am working on a report using eclipse-birt. I need to add superscript three ³ to the report. I send it from my java program as a data item. I have a string that has "\u00B3" as value and i send it. When i run a test class on java, I can see character on console. But when I create the birt report it prints another character which is ‡. I don't know what is the reason of this. I have Cp1254 encoding on my workspace. I use Eclipse. And on birt-report xml, it is using UTF-8 Encoding.

```
putParameter(birtDocumentType.Volume, "3 m" + "\u00B3"));
```

And birt xml has the below encoding;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

It prints 3 m‡ instead of 3 m³.

Thank you all !

Comment: Where is your code, your files?

Comment: @AHungerArtist I edited the question.

Comment: You don't mention the output format (HTML, PDF, ...). I'm pretty sure something is wrong with your code or with your data. BIRT has no problems with Unicode.

Comment: @hvb My output format is ps (postscript). Yes probably something wrong with my code, and I am asking about it. Is there a logical explanation for printing ‡ ?